# How to add Three table in one xib and also three connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I want to take three table and also do a three different connection on the same xib.Can any one help me. Any Demo.

Comment: what problem you are facing when adding three UITableView in xib?

Comment: it showing me null value

Comment: Do you have any demo related to this. I also want to pass 3 different JSON data in three different table.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
        
    [dataObj setLength:0];
      
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    
    [dataObj appendData:data];
    
}
I want to add three connection from three different link

Comment: any Demo for three connection from JSON Link and three table

Comment: It seems like you are a beginner. First try it by yourself then what issue you are facing that you can post here.Do some R&D that how to create a tableview first then pass some hardcoded value in that.Then check how to parse the JSON data in table view.You will get many demos also but prefer to write the code by seeing some sample so it will be helpful to you.But anyhow you can achieve it.All the best.

Comment: yes I am beginner. I know how to parse JSON data in tableview. But the main issue is. I want to pass three JSON Link in three different table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the IBOutlet of all there tables and also set the datasource and delegate of all 3 tables.

Now in all datasource and delegate method simply check like following

```
  if (tableView == self.tableview1) {
      //Do task for that table1
  }
  else if (tableView == self.tableview2) {
      //Do task for that table2
  }
  else {
      //Do task for that table3
  }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: ok. But how to use three connection NSURLConnection. I have three link and want two pass it into three different table

Comment: Create 3 different NSURLConnection and called your link with that, same as you have call single NSURLConnection request.

Comment: ok. but I need three different delegate

Comment: No. Just do same as tableview delegate method compare the NSURLConnection object with your globally created 3 different object.

Comment: using if else condition??

Comment: yes. Same as tableview.

Comment: But i am not able to add condition in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Try like this   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {if (tableView == self.tableview1) {
      return 20;
  }
  else if (tableView == self.tableview2) {
      return 10;
  }
  else {
      return 5;
  }}

Comment: Thank You very much it work...

Comment: Happy to help. Is your NSURLConnection problem solved?

Comment: Yes It Solved. Thank You.

Comment: How to accept answer..I dont have 15 reputation...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add . Just Set the `Tag` different and according to `tagValue` handle the data.

and connect the `datasource` and `delegate` all the tables.

Comment: Don't use `tag`, it's slow and error prone, use `IBOutlets` and simple compares.

Comment: ok. But how to use three connection NSURLConnection. I have three link and want two pass it into three different table

Comment: you can use for this thing .... Number of section 3 in one table and pass the data according to the response in the sections.

Or if you want to use with  NSURL Connection in different table then use tag,

And don't forgot   Reload data on table.

Answer (score 0):

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        return 5;
    } else if (tableView == self.tableView2) {
        return 10;
    } else if (tableView == self.tableView3) {
        return 20;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}`

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else if (tableView == self.tableView2) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell3" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    return cell;
}`

Comment: For NSURLConnection. there is also three .asmx link